# Conexão com banco de dados utilizando Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Minha dúvida, talvez não seja um tanto técnica, mas sim de melhor conceito, usabilidade, ou vantagens.

Tenho uma boa experiência em desenvolvimento asp.net utilizando webforms, e ultimamento busco expandir meus conhecimentos estudando asp.net mvc, e asp.net web api.

Seguindo um curso, aprendi a conectar na base de dados, sql server, e também consegui adaptar para mysql (o que geralmente utilizo mais), utilizando **ADO.NET Entity Data Model**. O qual cria a classe de `dbContext`, busca em minha base as tabelas todas que desejo e já cria as classes com as `properties`.

Minha dúvida, é se também posso conectar em minha base de dados sem utilizar o **ADO.NET Entity Data Model**, criando manualmente a string de conexão, criando meu dbContext, e classes manualmente?

Caso sim, gostaria de aprender um pouco melhor sobre as vantagens **ADO.NET Entity Data Model**, de usá-lo ou não.

Comment: Erico, esta abordagem é usualmente conhecida como code first, tem umas dicas aqui: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh972463.aspx. Tenho um exemplo publicado em http://impactacsharp2.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Roteiro/ImpactaCSharp2/Impacta.Repositorios.Ef.CodeFirst/OficinaDbContext.cs.

Comment: Valeu @VítorNeilAvelino, mas assim, Code first, eu gero a base de dados após eu ter criado as classes. E assim, talvez meu conceito esteja errado, mas por exemplo, quando utilizava webforms, eu já tinha a base de dados criada, e no meu projeto eu tinha uma classe que realiza a conexão e depois as classes CRUD. É válido, ou vantajoso pensar da mesma maneira em projetos mvc?

Comment: Erico, concordo que o termo code first confunde um pouco. Basicamente eu o interpreto como sendo uma alternativa para não precisar usar o designer oferecido inicialmente pelo EF. Você pode sim ter o banco criado primeiro e aí fazer o mapeamento manualmente, ou seja, criar uma classe em sua camada de acesso a dados que herde de DbContext e usar os templates que foram sugeridos nos links acima.

Comment: Isto não é Code First. Isto é Database First.

Comment: @EricoSouza O ADO.NET Entity Data Model é um provedor de conexão do Visual Studio com o banco de dados. Não entendi o que você quer em "conectar em minha base de dados sem utilizar o ADO.NET Entity Data Model".

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez talvez eu esteja um pouso desatualizado e aprendendo algumas coisas bem interessantes nos últimos tempos, por exemplo antes eu não utilizava o ADO.NET Entity Data Model, utilizava uma classe própria que criei nos tempos de faculdade, a uns 3 ou 4 anos atras. Ela me atendia perfeitamente nos projetos webforms, e funcionava enviando os comandos SQL para o banco. Então de certa forma não me preocupava. E agora estou pegando melhor intimidade com o ADO.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de estudar e pesquisar bastante e aprender também na prática, reconheço que em um projeto asp.net mvc, é muito útil a utilização do **ADO.NET Entity Data Model**. Tive um pouco de dificuldade no inicio para configurar a conexão com diferentes bancos que não fosse o **MS Sql Server,** como o **Mysql** e **Oracle**, mas depois foi tudo tranquilo, e é um conceito bem mais útil e diferente do que eu estava acostumado a utilizar.